Tensor product and extension of $\sigma$-weakly continuous linear map.

Let $M$ be a Von Neumann algebra and let $\Delta$ be a $\sigma$-weakly continuous unital $*$-morphism. We say that $\Delta$ is a comultiplication if $\Delta$ satisfies $(\Delta \otimes \iota)\Delta = (\iota \otimes \Delta)\Delta$. I have trouble understanding how $\Delta \otimes \iota$ and $\iota \otimes \Delta$ are defined as tensor products of maps are quite tricky to define. EDIT : I'd like to know how to extend the tensor product map $\Delta \otimes \iota$ to the Von Neumann algebra tensor product.

Let $G$ be a locally compact second countable topological group. For $g \in G$ we can consider the linear operator $\lambda_g : L^2(G) \to L^2(G)$ defined by $\lambda_g f(h) = f(g^{-1}h)$. We can then consider the Von Neumann algebra $W^*(G) = \mathrm{Vect}(\lambda(G))'' \subset \mathcal{B}(L^2(G))$. My goal is to equip $W^*(G)$ with a comultiplication. To do so, we define $\Delta(\lambda_g) = \lambda_g \otimes \lambda_g$ and extend $\Delta$ to $\mathrm{Vect}(\lambda(G))$ by linearity (I have a proof that operators of $\lambda(G)$ are linearly independants). As $W^*(G)$ is the $\sigma$-weak closure of $\mathrm{Vect}(\lambda(G))$, we know that any $\sigma$-weakly continuous extension of $\Delta$ is unique by I lack a justification of the existence of such an extension.


I'm pretty sure there should be a way to define these objects as they are fundamental in the theory of locally compact quantum groups but I can't find any source that provides a clear explaination of these facts.

For $1$, the following is a general fact:
Fact: Let $M, N, M_1, N_1$ be vNa’s, $\pi: M \to M_1$, $\phi: N \to N_1$ be normal $\ast$-homomorphisms, then there exists a unique normal $\ast$-homomorphism $\pi \otimes \phi: M \mathbin{\bar{\otimes}} N \to M_1 \mathbin{\bar{\otimes}} N_1$ such that $\pi \otimes \phi(x \otimes y) = \pi(x) \otimes \phi(y)$ for all $x \in M, y \in N$.
Proof sketch: Uniqueness is obvious. For existence, assume first that $\pi$ and $\phi$ are injective and $M_1, N_1$ acts on $K$ and $H$, respectively. Then $M$ acts as a vNa on $K$ through $\pi$ and $N$ acts as a vNa on $H$ through $\phi$, so by definition of vNa tensor product, $M \mathbin{\bar{\otimes}} N$ can be realized as a subalgebra of $B(K \otimes H)$, generated by operators of the form $\pi(x) \otimes \phi(y) \in M_1 \mathbin{\bar{\otimes}} N_1 \subset B(K \otimes H)$. The natural inclusion map $M \mathbin{\bar{\otimes}} N \subset M_1 \mathbin{\bar{\otimes}} N_1$ then is the desired map $\pi \otimes \phi$.
For the general case, $M = \mathrm{ker}(\pi) \oplus \pi(M)$ and $N = \mathrm{ker}(\phi) \oplus \phi(N)$, so,
$$M \mathbin{\bar{\otimes}} N = (\mathrm{ker}(\pi) \mathbin{\bar{\otimes}} \mathrm{ker}(\phi)) \oplus (\mathrm{ker}(\pi) \mathbin{\bar{\otimes}} \phi(N)) \oplus (\pi(M) \mathbin{\bar{\otimes}} \mathrm{ker}(\phi)) \oplus (\pi(M) \mathbin{\bar{\otimes}} \phi(N))$$
By the first paragraph, there is a natural embedding $\pi(M) \mathbin{\bar{\otimes}} \phi(N) \subset M_1 \mathbin{\bar{\otimes}} N_1$. The desired map $\pi \otimes \phi$ is simply this embedding pre-composed with the projection onto the fourth summand, from $M \mathbin{\bar{\otimes}} N$ to $\pi(M) \mathbin{\bar{\otimes}} \phi(N)$. $\square$
For $2$, this is an application of Fell’s absorption principle. To write it out explicitly, consider the unitary $U: L^2(G \times G) \to L^2(G \times G)$ defined by,
$$U(f)(g, h) = f(g, g^{-1}h)$$
Then,
$$\begin{split}
[U (\lambda_k \otimes 1) U^\ast](f)(g, h) &= [(\lambda_k \otimes 1) U^\ast](f)(g, g^{-1}h)\\
&= U^\ast(f)(k^{-1}g, g^{-1}h)\\
&= f(k^{-1}g, k^{-1}gg^{-1}h)\\
&= f(k^{-1}g, k^{-1}h)\\
&= (\lambda_k \otimes \lambda_k)(f)(g, h)
\end{split}$$
Thus, $[U (\lambda_k \otimes 1) U^\ast](f) = (\lambda_k \otimes \lambda_k)(f)$. So $\mathrm{Ad}_U = U \cdot U^\ast$ restricts to a map from $W^\ast(G) \simeq W^\ast(G) \otimes 1$ to $W^\ast(G) \mathbin{\bar{\otimes}} W^\ast(G)$ and sends $\lambda_g$ to $\lambda_g \otimes \lambda_g$ for all $g \in G$. Thus, it is the desired comultipication map $\Delta$.

Thanks for your answer ! For 2), is it possible to prove the existence of the extension without explicitly giving it ?

For 1), you're saying that there's absolutly no problem with defining tensor product of maps between vNa. Can we also  define slice maps this way ? The only definition I've seen is by using the fact that $L^1(H)^* = \mathcal{B}(H)$. (I'm refering to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4887125/1287797 )

@ValentinMassicot For (2), do you mean whether one can avoid writing down a unitary that explicitly implements this extension? In general, probably no. It is not the case that any group representation $G \to U(H)$ extends to a normal $\ast$-homomorphism $W^\ast(G) \to B(H)$. (For example, the trivial representation of an infinite discrete group $G$ cannot be extended to $W^\ast(G)$.) So some special properties of the comultiplication representation will need to be used. (Though there is an alternative proof in case $G$ is discrete using preservation of trace. It’s just more complicated.)

For 2) that's exactly what I meant. I guess I'll go with this one.

@ValentinMassicot For (1), that’s not what I said. The proof I provided only works if the maps in question are normal $\ast$-homomophisms, whereas slice maps are tensor products of identity maps with normal states, not $\ast$-homomorphisms. Now, it is actually true that you can define tensor products of normal unital completely positive maps, which would include both normal $\ast$-homomorphisms as well as normal states, but the proof of that is far longer.

Oh yes of course, states are not $*$-preserving.

@ValentinMassicot States are $\ast$-preserving. They are not homomorphisms because they are not multiplicative. (Though I just read the question you linked to. You are defining slice maps more generally than I would, so it’s not even states, just normal linear functionals, which certainly doesn’t even need to be $\ast$-preserving. In this case, you need an even more general result that tensor products of normal completely bounded maps are well-defined, which is true, but requires even more advanced machinery to prove.)

Thanks a lot for your answers !

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
